# When directory is not found add directory?

Tags: .htaccess

It should first check if the first /$1/ is a directory and if not add a directory before it.

E.G:
each of this URLs:

```
pizza
pizza/olives
pasta
pasta/lasagna
```

should go to:

```
menu/pizza
menu/pizza/olives
menu/pasta
menu/pasta/lasagna
```

Accordingly. How is this done?

Comment: This is off topic for StackOverflow and belongs on ServerFault. You probably know that though, given that you have 1.5k whatever they're called...

Comment: you are right, voted to close

Comment: Thanks. Un-downvoted. You can't close once it's been answered, but it'll probably be automatically migrated once other power users vote to move.

Comment: I just posted in server fault so power users > delete

Comment: @Mahmoud, Liso - you are mistaken. mod_rewrite questions are not automatically off-topic on SO. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39063/

Comment: @Pekka I'm under the impression it's only on-topic if ties in to the code somehow. Given that no programming language, code, library, framework, or coding technique is mentioned and the only tag is `.htaccess`, I'd say it's off-topic.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi If that's true about 25% of all the 10k questions with the htaccess tag should be close/moved. Mod_rewrite uses RegEx, which kind of is a programming-language :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^(pizza(/olives)?|pasta(/lasagna)?)  menu/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generic version than Sp4cecat's

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/(.*)$ /menu/$0 [R=302,L]
```